# Ansible: How to combine multiple tags to single `all` tag?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I want to combine multiple tags to a single `all` tag while running playbook. In example, for a command like

```sh
ansible-playbook apache.yml -e 'TARGET=bs' -i inventories/devqa-servers.ini -b -K -u root --ask-vault-pass --ask-pass --tags 'normal_vars,  install, configure, ssl, custom_config, services, mdm, enterpriseenrollment_80, enroll'
```

I want to combine all the tags into a file or common tag and call only that tag like below

```sh
ansible-playbook apache.yml -e 'TARGET=bs' -i inventories/devqa-servers.ini -b -K -u root --ask-vault-pass --ask-pass --tags 'all'
```

so the `all` tag will have all other tags. Do we have any such way in Ansible to do it?

Answer (score 0):

According the documentation [Selecting or skipping tags when you run a playbook](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_tags.html#using-tags) this functionality is available out-of-box and the default behavior

> *`ansible-playbook` offers five tag-related command-line options:*
>
> *`--tags all` - run all tasks, ignore tags (default behavior)*